# Not sure how to use WaitForNavigationAsync()

Tags: c#, .net, puppeteer-sharp

I have this code

```
public static async Task ClickSearchButton(IPage page)
{
    //await page.ClickAsync("#searchBtn");
    //Thread.Sleep(5000);

    await Task.WhenAll(page.ClickAsync("#searchBtn"), page.WaitForNavigationAsync(new NavigationOptions() { WaitUntil = new[] { WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle0 } }));
}
```

The commented out portion works most of the time, but I'd like to remove the Sleep's.  I've tried MANY different things that I've found while searching for the solution, but I can't seem to get it to work.  When I run this code, it comes back with:

```
System.TimeoutException: Timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
```

I've tried all the WaitUntilNavigation options (Load, DOMContentLoaded, Networkidle0, Networkidle2).

What I'm trying to do is after I fill out the form, I click the Search button.  A whole new page doesn't load, it just populates below the form options.  I'm assuming it's JavaScript that's running.

Answer (score 0):

The error your're getting is saying that Puppeteer has timed out waiting for the element. Since it works some of the time, you can increase the timeout.

If you look at the source code, you can see the timeout is referenced in two ways
https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/blob/master/lib/PuppeteerSharp/FrameManager.cs#L98

You can do this globally - this will be used for **all navigation queries**

```
// Set the default timeout to 10 seconds
TimeoutSettings.NavigationTimeout = 10_000;

await page.ClickAsync("#searchBtn");
await page.WaitForNavigationAsync();
```

Alternatively, you can set the timeout on the selector call to affect just this query

```
await page.ClickAsync("#searchBtn");
await page.WaitForNavigationAsync(new NavigationOptions
{
    Timeout = 10_000
});
```

Comment: I'm using PuppeteerSharp v9.0.2 and I don't have the SetDefaultTimeout() or the PageWaitForNavigationOption().

Comment: Also, when I mentioned that is works most of the time, I was referring to the commented out code, the one with the sleep in it.  The await Task.WhenAll(page.ClickAsync("#searchBtn"), page.WaitForNavigationAsync(new NavigationOptions() { WaitUntil = new[] { WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle0 } })); NEVER works.  I normally run it headless, but for debugging I bring up the browser.  When I'm watching it, the data shows up like I'm expecting, it just never continues when I use WaitUntilNavigation.  When I use the commented out code with the Sleep, it will run 90-95% of the time without problems.

Comment: Apologies, I'd referenced Playwright, not Pupeteer. The answer has been updated now. When you use the Task.WhenAll() syntax, both requests are fired at the same time, so it will timeout sooner. This is likely why it isn't working

Comment: Thank you!  I tried both suggestions and it's still not working.  It's not really a timing issue.  The problem I'm having is it's never getting past the await page.WaitForNavigationAsnyc call.  I even put the timeout up to 60 seconds.  All the data shows up on the page, that method just doesn't get fired.  I guess my hobby programming is going to have to learn deep debugging now.

Comment: If the navigation isn't awaiting, it might be the page isn't actually navigating. Or the opposite, it's navigated before you've awaited